# select date_add mysql issue

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

i have a table `loans` in a database with the schema that like this

```
loans
-----
period (vchar) ' but it contains number string
date
amt
user
```

i  needed to select all the records from a loans where the the `date` + `period` is equal to or greater than current date. when i execute the query below

```
SELECT * 
FROM loans
WHERE DATE( DATE_ADD( DATE, INTERVAL period
DAY ) ) >= CURRENT_DATE
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

i get all the records in the loans table. what is the problem?

Comment: We need to see what `period` values look like.

Comment: Is `pay_period` intended as `period`? Are they different columns or is one a typo here?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: i update my post. the period is a varchar field, but its numeric

Comment: @Smith *What* does your data in that column look like?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO numbers 15, 30, 10 etc

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it was a typo, its corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT columnList
FROM loans
WHERE CURDATE() < DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL pay_period DAY)
```